# How to test crud ajax requests in Sencha Fiddle

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-fiddle

I would like to use a Sencha Fiddle to test create and update events. I want to investigate, how configuration of the Proxy and format of the response must work together to get successful crud operations.

I thought of creating a Sencha Fiddle and read/write the data to an external webservice, instead of reading it from `Mock Data` folder. It looks as there is no way to fetch an external resource from within a fiddle. [This fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j8d) at least doesn't work, it does not make any request (using Chrome DevTools).

Am I seraching in the right direction ? Is ther a way to test Extjs communication with backend without making a full test installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that fiddle.sencha.com will not allow external Ajax requests to be made, you can load in external resources from the mock data option but I think it routes all requests locally.

You would also encounter cross domain request issues even if Sencha Fiddle allowed it, Its generally used for testing/demo purposes in which you should be able to provide mock data.

For anything beyond that you'd likely be better working locally or on a development server. I personally either test it locally or use online services such as AppFog. I was going to suggest trying [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) but again, You'd likely encounter cross domain issues anyway unless your using CORS.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make a working ExtJs fiddle on jsfiddle. I need to reproduce my problem there to be able to ask a meaningful question here.